# Show that ${\rm Var}\, \mathfrak{X}$ is a variety.

Tags: group-theory, universal-algebra

This is part of **Exercise 2.3.7** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this MSE search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Buniversal-algebra%5D+intersection+of+varieties+), it is new to MSE.

*(Note that "variety" here is in the sense of universal algebra.)*

### The Details:

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

On page 56, *ibid.*,

> Let $F$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $F$. If $w=x_{i_1}^{l_1}\dots x_{i_r}^{l_r}\in W$ and $g_1,\dots, g_r$ are elements of a group $G$, we define the *value* of the word $w$ at $(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ to be $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)=g_1^{l_1}\dots g_{r}^{l_r}$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by all values in $G$ of words in $W$ is called the *verbal subgroup* of $G$ determined by $W$,
>
> $$W(G)=\langle w(g_1,g_2,\dots) \mid g_i\in G, w\in W\rangle.$$

On page 57, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $G$ is any group, a normal subgroup $N$ is said to be *$W$-marginal* in $G$ if
>
> $$w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)=w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)$$
>
> for all $g_i\in G, a\in N$ and all $w(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$ in $W$. This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i\equiv h_i \mod N, (1\le i\le r)$, always implies that $w(g_1,\dots, g_r)=w(h_1,\dots, h_r)$.
>
> [The] $W$-marginal subgroups of $G$ generate a normal subgroup which is also $W$-marginal. This is called *the $W$-marginal of $G$* and is written $$W^*(G).$$

On page 57, *ibid.*,

> A [. . .] *class of groups* $\mathfrak{X}$ is a class - not a set - whose members are groups and which enjoys the following properties: (i) $\mathfrak{X}$ contains a group of order $1$; and (ii) $G_1\cong G\in\mathfrak{X}$ always implies $G_1\in\mathfrak{X}$.

On page 58, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots $, the class of all groups $G$ such that $W(G)=1$, or equivalently $W^*(G)=G$, is called the *variety* $\mathfrak{B}(W)$ determined by $W$.

### The Question:

> If $\mathfrak{X}$ is any class of groups, define ${\rm Var}\,\mathfrak{X}$ to be the intersection of all varieties that contain $\mathfrak{X}$. Prove that ${\rm Var}\,\mathfrak{X}$ is a variety.

### Thoughts:

My first impression was that this exercise is relatively easy. The proof ought to run along the same lines as any old proof of an intersection of *whatevers* being a *whatever*. Digging a little deeper, though, things are not so simple.

<strike>At an extreme case, consider $\mathfrak{X}=\{1\}$, where $1$ is the trivial group up to isomorphism. Since, for any set of words $W$, we have $W(1)=1$, we can deduce that each variety $\mathfrak{B}(W)$ of groups contain $\mathfrak{X}$, which implies ${\rm Var}\, \{1\}$ is simply the variety of all groups.</strike>

One approach might be to let $G\in{\rm Var}\, \mathfrak{X}$ for some class $\mathfrak{X}$. Then the aim would be to show that, since $G$ is in each variety $\mathfrak{W}$ that contains $\mathfrak{X}$, we have $\mathfrak{W}=\mathfrak{B}(W)$ for some set of words $W$, so that . . . Yeah, this is where I'm stuck. See: I need to construct an appropriate set $W_{\mathfrak{X}}$ of words for which

$${\rm Var}\, \mathfrak{X}=\mathfrak{B}(W_{\mathfrak{X}}).$$

I'm not sure . . .

I have a hunch that something like

$$W_{\mathfrak{X}}=\bigcap_{W: \mathfrak{X}\subseteq \mathfrak{B}(W)}W$$

might work.

Nowhere have I used the definition of a class of groups.

Please help :)

Comment: $Var(\{1\})$ is **not** the variety of all groups, it's just $\{1\}$ itself. (Consider the equation $x=y$.) That said, your broader hunch is right: the intersection of any collection of varieties is again a variety, and so in particular the intersection of all varieties containing $\mathfrak{X}$ is the smallest variety containing $\mathfrak{X}$.

Comment: I think you confused $\mathrm{Var}(\{1\})$, the variety generated by the trivial group (which is just the trivial group), with the variety determined by $e$, the trivial *word*. The variety determined by the trivial word is the variety of all groups. But the word that determines the variety $\mathrm{Var}(\{1\})$ is $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf{V}_1$ is the variety determined by the set of words $W_1$; and $\mathbf{V}_2$ is the variety determined by the set of words $W_2$. So the groups of $\mathbf{V}_1$ are precisely the groups for which $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $w\in W_1$; and the groups in $\mathbf{V}_2$ are precisely the groups for which $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $w\in W_2$.

What are the groups in $\mathbf{V}_1\cap\mathbf{V}_2$? Precisely the groups $G$ for which $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $w\in W_1\cup W_2$. So $\mathbf{V}_1\cap\mathbf{V}_2$ is the variety determined by the set of words $W_1\cup W_2$.

The same is true for an arbitrary intersection: if $\mathbf{V}_i$ is defined by the set of words $W_i$, then $\cap\mathbf{V}_i$ is determined by the set of words $\cup W_i$.

---

More generally, what you have here is a Galois connection. Consider the partially ordered set of subsets of $F_{\omega}$, the free group on countably many variables, interpreted as group words. And consider the class (or set in an appropriate universe) of collections of groups.

Given a subset $J$ of $F_{\omega}$, we can consider the collection $J^*$ of all groups $G$ such that $w(G)=\{e\}$ for each $w\in J$; that is, the groups that satisfy every word in $J$. And given a collection of groups $\mathfrak{G}$, we can let $\mathfrak{G}^*$ be the collection of all elements $w$ of $F_{\omega}$ such that $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $G\in\mathfrak{G}$. Note that for $J\subseteq F_{\omega}$ and $\mathfrak{G}$, we have
$$\mathfrak{G}\subseteq J^*\iff J\subseteq\mathfrak{G}^*.$$
Indeed: for every $G\in\mathfrak{G}$ we have $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $w\in J$, if and only if  every $w\in J$ has the property that $w(G)=\{e\}$ for all $G\in\mathfrak{G}$.

Thus we have a Galois connection, which establishes an anti-isomorphism between the “closed” subsets of $F_{\omega}$, and the “closed” collections of groups. The closed collections of groups are the varieties; the closed collections of $F_{\omega}$ are the equational theories. The anti-isomorphism correspondence tells you that the intersection of varieties is the variety corresponding to the union of subsets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be (per your analysis of $\{1\}$, maybe you're mixing up union and intersection?). Suppose $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of varieties. Let $E_i$ be the equational theory of $V_i$, so that $V_i$ is exactly the class of models of $E_i$. Then the intersection $V:=\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i$ is exactly the class of models of $\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i$; since the latter is a set of equations, we get that $V$ is a variety.

This indeed uses nothing about groups. Details about groups enter the picture when we look for *concrete(ish) descriptions of* various varieties of groups, but they play no role in this general structural result.

---

The above uses the "model of a set of equations" definition of a variety. If instead we define a variety as a class of structures closed under taking homomorphisms, substructures, and arbitrary products, then the result is a consequence of the more general fact that **a collection of classes of structures defined by closure conditions is automatically closed under arbitrary intersections**.